# chrome 38 screen size developer tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I noticed with the new update chrome added a lot of great features for web developers however when you had the developer tools open and dragged the screen it used to tell you the screen width size in the top right corner. Now it just has  the measurement up top but it's very had to determine exact pixel size because it is ruler marks. Is there any way to get back the old exact pixel number of the screen width size?

I Googled around a bit and couldn't find much on this topic. Any help would be much appreciated as it helps me quite a bit in writing precise media queries. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn) screen ruler. It helps me a lot. With it you can measure size of any object you want.

Answer (score 0):

when using chrome you can get more extensions you can use this 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en-US' or normally go to "customized and controller->settings->extensions->Get more extensions" and search any extension what you want.
thank you :)